# Elbow between arc pipes

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Considering:

- Red lines are neutral axes of arc pipes
- Orange lines are potential pipe borders
- Purple lines are potential pipe cuts
- Pink points are center of elbow circles

I am searching an algorithm to bend 2 arc pipes using 1 of the 8 or less potential elbows. I know:

- R<sub>pipe</sub> the radius of the pipe width
- R<sub>arc1</sub> the radius of the first arc pipe
- R<sub>arc2</sub> the radius of the second arc pipe
- R<sub>elbow</sub> the radius of the elbow interior
- All points defining the arc pipes (start, end, center)

**Example 1: Wide View**

[image]

In this example, the correct elbow must be the one that is located at the bottom:

**Example 1: Zoomed in View**

[image]

But there are a lot of different configurations, some other examples:

**Example 2**

[image]

**Example 3**

[image]

**Example 4**

[image]

If you have an idea about the logic of an algorithm to find the correct elbow, some help will bee very appreciated!

**Example 5**

The case of double crossing with no enough space in the "loop":

[image]

**Example 6: A representation in a 3D context**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some more context / explanation to your question. It is unclear what constituted the "correct elbow" or even exactly what an "elbow circle" is. Also what do the black lines and blue dots represent?

Comment: I just added a picture to understand the elbow principle, sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: That zoomed in diagram helped.

Comment: In the second example where the pipes cross twice which elbows are correct ones? I can tell for the examples where there is only point of intersection. Just to check my understanding in the third one is the bottom left elbow of the lower set of four the correct elbow? And in the fourth is it the lowest one on its own?

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, I updated solutions waited.

Comment: I am also curious about the second example.  Even if you identify which intersection you want to create an elbow for, the elbow configuration depends on the arc pipes being essentially coplanar, doesn't it?  How does that work if the other intersection point precludes that?

Comment: The elbow must be placed at the nearest point of the pipe arcs 'break'. If there is no space for elbow in the "loop", the loop have to be ignored and the elbow is placed at the first crossing. In this case, the second crossing solution will no exists.

Comment: Oh so looking at your second example elbows only occur at ends of pipes and overlapping is allowed.

Comment: Arc pipes are coplanar and overlapping is effectively allowed. There can be only one elbow between the two arc pipes and this elbow have to be nearest possible to the arcs junction.

Comment: With so many examples I've gone and added numbers to each to make these easier to refer to.

Comment: Both Example 2 and Example 5 cross twice. What determines if there is not enough space?

Comment: There is 4 black circles, that circles are defined by the center of arc pipes and a radius of arc pipe ± (Rpipe + Relbow). The intersection of the black circles give the possible solutions. In case of non black circle crossing, there is no 8 possible solutions but less. If there is not enough space, no solution exists in this loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the center point of each pipe is less than $180^\circ$ from both ends.

Steps to find elbow:

- find end of intersection of each pipe (assuming you already can do that)
- determine direction of rotation from intersection towards the middle for each pipe. I.e. clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation. (this requires middle to be less than $180^\circ$ from the end)
- construct vector at end of each pipe parallel to the length pointing. The direction of the vector should match the direction of the rotation from last step
- add the two vectors from each pipe
- resultant vector will point close to correct elbow
- find angle between this vector and a vector constructed from point of intersection to each potential elbow
- smallest angle will be correct elbow